# find the parametric equation of a line in $2$ space

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Given $2x-3y=5$ find the parametric equation of the line in $\mathbb R^2$

First I set $x$ to $0$ to find point $p1=(0,\frac{-5}{3})$ and $x$ to 1 to find point $p2=(1,-1)$ $p2-p1=v$ parallel to the line. $v=(1,\frac{2}{3})$

Now I have a point on the line $p2$ or $p1$ and a vector parallel to the line and can write the line as $(x,y)=(1,-1)+t(1,\frac{2}{3});t\in \mathbb R$

Yet this is completly different wrom the answer in my book $(x,y)=(4,1)+t(3,2);t \in \mathbb R$ what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The big thing you're doing wrong is to use the word "the" when referring to parametric equations. A given curve can be described by many different sets of parametric equations. For example, it's pretty obvious that $(x,y) =(t,t)$ and $(x,y) =(t+1,t+1)$ and even $(x,y) =(t^3,t^3)$ all describe the line $y=x$. It's impossible for your book to give you "the answer", because there are many possible answers, all equally valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, your answer and the book's answer are equivalent.

Note that

$$\begin{align}(x, y) &= (1, -1) + t\left(1, \frac{2}{3}\right)\\
&= (1 , -1) + \frac{t}{3}(3, 2)\\
&= (4, 1) + \left(\frac{t}{3} - 1\right)(3, 2)\end{align}$$

so if you made the substitution $t' = \frac{t}{3} - 1$, you get

$$(x, y) = (4, 1)+ t'(3,2)$$

The geometrical intuition is that two lines are equivalent if their directions are parallel, and their constant terms differ by a scalar multiple of their equivalent directions.